# Count and Group by Month name in railes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the code I have

```
 MediaDownload.select("COUNT(*) AS count_all,MONTHNAME(created_at) AS created_at ").group('created_at').count
```

but instead of getting a sql(mysql) code like this :

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS created_at FROM `media_downloads` GROUP BY created_at
```

I get this :

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, created_at AS created_at FROM `media_downloads` GROUP BY created_at
```

What I am doing wrong. Is there any solutions to get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excess `count` in your ActiveRecord query syntax, so the following one

```
MediaDownload.select("COUNT(*) AS count_all,MONTHNAME(created_at) AS created_at ").group('created_at')
```

generates sql query you want